# Wrapping an executable with nullable parameters

Tags: powershell

In `cmd` I can write a batch file like so, which will provide an alias for an executable.

SuperUtil.bat

```
call Mine.Library.SuperUtil.exe %*
```

So I can call

```
SuperUtil -t SomeParam
```

This is my attempt of a PowerShell equivalent

```
Start-Process Mine.Library.SuperUtil.exe -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList $args
```

However when I call it with no parameters I get an error.

> Start-Process : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ArgumentList'.
>   The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection
>   contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any
>   null values and then try the command again.

I've tried the following but doesn't pass the arguments, plus it's quite verbose:

```
if ($args -ne $Null)
{
    Start-Process Mine.Library.SuperUtil.exe -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList $args -Wait
}
else
{
    Start-Process Mine.Library.SuperUtil.exe -NoNewWindow -Wait
}
```

So I want to optionally pass the arguments or not, in order to explore the command line options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [splatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) if you want to provide optional parameter arguments:

```
$params = @{}
if($args){
    $params['ArgumentList'] = $args
}
Start-Process Mine.Library.SuperUtil.exe -NoNewWindow -Wait @params
```

If the `$params` hashtable is empty by the time `Start-Process` is invoked, it'll simply be ignored.

You can also squash the other parameter arguments into the hashtable if you want:

```
$params = @{
    FilePath    = 'Mine.Library.SuperUtil.exe'
    NoNewWindow = $true
    Wait        = $true
}
if($args){
    $params['ArgumentList'] = $args
}
Start-Process @params
```

Makes maintenance of the script easy (but obviously still quite verbose compared to the batch file alternative)

Comment: It might be verbose, but it's also clear. I like it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read [About Automatic Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables):

> **$ARGS**
>  Contains **an array of the undeclared parameters** and/or parameter values that are passed to a function, script, or
>   script block.

Therefore, check **`if ($args.Count -ne 0)`** rather than `if ($args -ne $Null)` as the automatic variable `$args` is always an array (and never `$Null`).